# Layering divs ordering

Tags: html, css, layer

I am having some difficulty with layering my divs. I have created a sample of the problematic area.

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/332FJ/1/)

By looking at it you can see a background image - on top of that are two blue boxes and slightly transparent black box. I require the box to be behind the two boxes but on top of the background image.

Now I did try assigning a z-index to all elements but it didn't change a thing?

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_2_of_4">
                "headline here"
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_1_of_4">
                sub head
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="headerband"></div>    

</div>


.hero{
    position:relative;
    height:60%;
    background-image:url(http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/e520/sample/images/sample_03.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.headerband{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
    height: 20%; 
    margin-top: -30px; 
    float:left; 
    z-index: -1; 
    width: 100%;
}

/* Main Container */
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;            
}



/* Respinsive grid */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}



/*  Grid of four  */
.span_4_of_4 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
    width: 74.6%;
    background-color: blue;     
}
.span_2_of_4 {
    width: 49.2%;
    background-color: #008394;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align:center;  
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    margin-top: 370px;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
    width: 28.8%;
    background-color: #00C1DB;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accomplished what you needed by doing this

```
.headerband{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
    height: 20%; 
    margin-top: -30px; 
    float:left; 

    /* Drop this line => z-index: 0;  */

    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;

    /* You can use a z-index of 1 or higher. I opted for 10 */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/332FJ/5/)

**UPDATE:**

The `z-index` property won't work [unless you set the `position` property of the element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). By default the CSS `position` property is `static` ([Read more about the position property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)]. Valid values are `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`, which allows you to position elements by supplying it with a `top`, `left`, `bottom`, or `right`. Normally you set either the `top` or `bottom` properties along with a horizontal location (i.e. `left` or `right`). Relative positioning is always *relative* to its parent element, normally you want to use it within a parent element that has been absolutely positioned. Fixed positioning will ensure that the positioned element will always stay visible, regardless of whether the user scrolls away or not. This one is useful, in my experience, for sticky navigation menus.

Since you weren't using absolute positioning for the `.container`, I opted to make it relative, then give it a `z-index` that was higher than the `headerband`.

<strike>As for why I set the `.headerband` to a non-negative value, this is a design decision on my part. I always work with z-indexes of 0 or higher. You will see in the above link that a negative z-index is valid. To me it's more natural to work with non-negatives.</strike> I noticed that `.headerband` isn't using absolutely positioned. I thought it was. Ignore this paragraph.

Comment: You should explain what you did and why it works rather than just feeding him the answer. Also, `z-index: 0` is useless. Why add it?

Comment: @TylerH I appreciate your participation but I now understand by seeing it for myself - your explanation is far less informative.

Comment: @user3520443 I'm glad you finally understand it, but it's not possible for this answer to be more informative; the first sentence of my answer is more informative than this entire post :-)

Comment: @TylerH , thanks for requesting additional information. I updated my answer as you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property will not work unless you use the `position` property as well on the element. For example:

```
position: fixed;
position: absolute;
position: relative;
```

If you're not familiar with what these do, you can read more about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/). And [this blog post](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) details how z-index and positioning work together.

Comment: I am familiar with positions but I am not sure why the layers arnt sitting behind each other? Are you able to show me in a fiddle?

Comment: @user3520443 The elements are not layering properly because your `z-index` (which is doing the layering) is not being applied. As I said in the first sentence of my answer, you need to apply `position` for your `z-index` to work. You don't have it applied to `.headerband`